# Formatting keyword explanation to wrap to end of keyword

Tags: formatting, lists

I'm looking for a way to format keyword translation in a way, where keywords are left-justified, but their explanation does not wrap to the beggining of the line, but rather is indented by the length of the keyword.

One obvious thing that came to my mind was to use a table - but then all explataions/translations are indented by the largest keyword:

```tex
  \begin{tabular}[c]{ l p{8cm} }
    \textbf{key} & some value not long enough to get split, but lasts till the end \\
    \textbf{super long keyword} & some value which might be so long that it is being split over multiple lines. \\
  \end{tabular}
```

[image: Rendering]

This causes the explanations for shorter keys be indented too much, making it less readable. The only thing I could come up with to remedy this, was to create a table per word, but having to specify size of the paragraph manually per table seems like anti-TeX way of doing things:

```tex
  \begin{tabular}[c]{ l p{12cm} }
    \textbf{key} & some value not long enough to get split, but lasts till the end \\
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{tabular}[c]{ l p{8cm} }
    \textbf{super long keyword} & some value which might be so long that it is being split over multiple lines. \\
  \end{tabular}
```

[image: Rendering]

I sadly couldn't figure out how can I get the expected results in a different way. Probably lacking the use of some specific words in my search.

Is there a better way to do this?

My use case:

I have some domain/tool specific keywords and I want to have a subsection deticated to explaining them in such short format.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky, but here's a possible solution with a `description`-based environment, using `enumitem`. Basically, the idea is to place the content of every item of the list in a `minipage` with the correct width. To keep the usual syntax of a list environment, I defined a new `keywords` list environment in which `\item` is redefined to place the `minipage`s automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\olditem\item
\newlength{\currentlabelwidth}
\newcommand*{\changeitem}{%
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
        \ifdim\currentlabelwidth>0pt
            \end{minipage}%
        \else\fi%
        \settowidth{\currentlabelwidth}{##1}%
        \olditem[##1]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\currentlabelwidth}
    }%
}
\newlist{keywords}{description}{1}
\setlist[keywords]{
    font=\bfseries, 
    before=\changeitem,
    after=\end{minipage}\let\item\olditem,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{keywords}
    \item[key] some value not long enough to get split, but lasts till the end.
    \item[other key] some value which might be so long that it is being split over multiple lines.
    \item[super long keyword] some value which might be so long that it is being split over multiple lines.
\end{keywords}
\end{document}
```

There might be a better way to do this, though. I thought `enumitem` would allow the left margin to adapt to the label's width, but I didn't find any simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to have lists inside the explanations, here's a way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{showkeywords}
 {%
  \par % end the previous paragraph
  \addvspace{\topsep}% some vertical separation
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% no indentation here
  \let\item\showkeywordsitem
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\def\showkeywordsitem[#1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}
  \settowidth{\leftskip}{\textbf{#1\quad}}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{#1\quad}}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{showkeywords}
\item[key] some value not long enough to get split, but lasts till the end

\item[super long keyword] some value which might be so long that it is being 
  split over multiple lines.

\item[another key] which has a very long explanation split into different
  paragraphs.

  Here is the second paragraph of the explanation, which is indented the
  same as the previous one.
\end{showkeywords}

\end{document}
```

The syntax is the same as the `description` environment. The idea is that `\item[key]` measures the width of the key and then sets the hanging indentation via `\leftskip`. The key is inserted as a zero width box protruding to the left.

Some vertical space is inserted between entries.

[image]